# What would be the Mean Squared error of the Uncorrected Sample Variance?

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, mean-square-error

I am trying to compute the MSE of $\hat{\sigma}^2$, where $\hat{\sigma}^2= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N (x_i - \mu)^2$ for i.i.d samples $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^N$ normally distributed. I get the following calculation:

$$
\begin{align}
\text{MSE} \, (\hat{\sigma}^2) &= \text{Var}(\hat{\sigma}^2) + \text{Bias}^2(\hat{\sigma}^2)\\
&= \mathbb{E}[\hat{\sigma}^4] + \mathbb{E} [\hat{\sigma}^2]^2 + \mathbb{E}[\hat{\sigma}^2] - \sigma^2
\end{align}
$$

I am stuck here on how to calculate $\mathbb{E}[\hat{\sigma}^4]$ ?
Any help or direction is appreciated a lot. Thanks!

Comment: So you are basically trying to compute MSE of the MSE of $n$ values chosen from a normal distribution?

Comment: @VarunVejalla I don't think so. I am trying to compute the MSE of the biased estimator of variance $\hat{\sigma}^2$. The MSE is of biased and unbiased sample variance is mentioned here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error#Variance 
However, there's no derivation/proof.

Comment: Presumably your $\mu$ is known. If $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{X_i-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\sim \chi^2_n$.